# Notation for lengths

Tags: lengths, syntax

I've noticed that when you set length, you can not only write `\setlength{X}{3.14cm}` but `\setlength{X}{=3.14cm}` as well. It looks like there is not any difference between those notations but I'd like to know why there is a possibility to use notation with "=" sign.

Comment: You could as well type `\setlength{\X}{\@firstoftwo{3.14}{Hey! It's pi}cm}` if in a `\makeatletter` context, but this doesn't mean you should. `;-)`

Comment: _how_ did you notice that?????? (without starting from the implementation and just inferring that the `=` would drop through by accident? )Surely no documentation suggests that does it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I knew `\setlength{X}{Y}` expands to `{X Y\relax}` (I've read it in documentation) and then when experimenting with those notations I discovered the possibility of using `=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\setlength` is a LaTeX macro which is defined as:

```
\def\setlength#1#2{#1 #2\relax}
```

So `\setlength{\mylength}{1cm}` expands to `\mylength 1cm`.

The equals sign in assignments is optional, in TeX so:

```
\mylength 1cm
```

is equivalent to

```
 \mylength=1cm
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please give me the source of this information? I've searched for assignments syntax in TeX but I didn't found anything helpful.

Comment: @BartłomiejSługocki Other than the TeX Book itself, (which is not freely available), the best free source for TeX itself is Victor Eijkhout's *TeX by Topic* which you can find using `texdoc` in your distribution. For the source documentation of the LaTeX kernel, you can look at `source2e`, also available as part of your distribution via `texdoc`.